# Title not showing on chrome tab from brackets

Tags: tabs, page-title

New to HTML, learning on lynda.com. On one of the exercises I'm typing the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="A page for exploring HTML 
  documents">
<title>Basic HTML document</title>
</head>
</html>
```

The title is not showing up on the chrome browser tab, instead of "Basic HTML document", it's showing "doctype.htm". Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: It is showing up in the latest Chrome.

Comment: Please edit the question title to reflect the actual question and not your experience level.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip on being more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Depending your browser when you will see the title.

Example Safari on Mac, try adding bookmark to see the current name:

[image]

Example in Firefox V57, the name is i the tab:

[image]

So the HTML code is correct.  It's the what the browser has chosen to display depending on settings in the browser.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using brackets, when I try to bookmark it shows up the same. When i use text editor on mac, it shows properly on chrome. I have a lot of learning to do, I appreciate you taking the time to try and help me out!